# How many regional Nintendo eShops are there?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds

I have recently noticed that the European and the US eShop have significantly different offers (special deals, virtual console, etc.) so I was wondering how many regional eShops there are.

While we’re at it: Apart from the offers, are there other differences, e.g. prices, types of content?

Btw this information can be useful for people who live in countries in which the eShop isn’t provided at all (in my case, Croatia) and who have to pick a different country in order to “unlock” eShop access.

Comment: with the Australian eShop there will be a price difference, brought to you by the "F*** Australia Tax"

Comment: @Memor-X I’m paying in the UK eShop normally with my Croatian VISA. Why couldn’t people from Australia simply use a different eShop then? Or is Nintendo letting me do this because a Croatian eShop doesn’t exist…

Comment: Because stores block the use of international cards, ie you can't use an Australian card on a UK Store, from my understanding Croatia is apart of Europe so it's cards should be valid on the UK store. *"although there may still be certain limits, such as the inability to use credit or debit cards to purchase content or add funds, unless said cards are issued by banks in supported regions"*

Answer (score 3):

Official there are [27](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nintendo_eShop#Availability):

- Australia
- Austria
- Belgium
- Canada
- Czech Republic
- Denmark
- Finland
- France
- Germany
- Greece
- Ireland
- Italy
- Japan
- Luxembourg
- Mexico
- Netherlands
- New Zealand
- Norway
- Poland
- Portugal
- Russia
- South Africa
- Spain
- Sweden
- Switzerland
- United Kingdom
- United States

There isn't any list of things that are different, also because that varies way too much with time. From wikipedia again:

> In spite of the fact that all global PAL version Nintendo eShop users have access to identical hardware and servers, content availability does vary between local versions of the eShop in European and Oceanian continents due to legal reasons and differences in localisation entities.

In general you can say something like this from [gamefaqs](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/997614-nintendo-3ds/63631245):

**General - Affected by Region**

- Some 'Versus/Multiplayer' modes on 3DS/eShop titles
- Some "Download Play" on 3DSWare games
- Speciall MII via Spotpass
- Keyboard Layout* (Note for EU)
- Nintendo Video videos

**Japan**

- More eShop titles and demos
- Special Mii QR Codes (~150+)
- Foreign Credit Cards allowed on eShop
- Fire Emblem and OniTore puzzles

**North America**

- Netflix
- Can only use NA credit cards (? Someone confirm this?)

But I thought for example that Germany will get a different Rating for Bayonetta 2 (although for WiiU) then the rest of EU. And so there will be many more little differences that can change, especially the price.